# Firestore .get() promise stuck on pending

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using React and Firebase to create a small app. I'm trying to check for a document related to users in my firestore database where the document ID is the same as the uid generated by firebase auth, but for some reasons the .get() promise stays as pending, causing the .exists() function to throw an error (TypeError: userDoc.exists is not a function). I initially thought it was a problem with my db rules, so I changed them so anyone could read and write to the database (not secure I know, the rules will be changed later).

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Even after this, I still cannot retrieve the document. Below is my code.

```
let userDoc = db.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid)
console.log(userDoc);
userDoc = userDoc.get();
console.log(userDoc);
userDoc = userDoc.exists();
```

db is a Firestore object created using

```
admin.initializeApp()
db = admin.firestore()
```

and `let userDoc = db.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid)` results in a DocumentReference object. The document exists in firestore, but I just for some reason cannot access it in my react app. I've written a cloud function also working with firestore, and it has has had no problem reading and writing to my db. I feel like I'm missing something here and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I suggest starting with the JavaScript examples in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userDoc.get();` is `promise`, and it's making a request via `.get()` so it will be on pending state.

And change `exists()` to `exists`. **[REF](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)**

```
userDoc.get().then(data => {
   console.log(data , data.exists); //<--- Try to check here
});

console.log(userDoc); // <--- this will give you Promise with pending state
```

OR you can use `async await` :

```
async function getData() { // <------ async
    let userDoc = db.collection('Users').doc(currentUser.uid)
    console.log(userDoc);
    userDoc = await userDoc.get(); // <------ await
    console.log(userDoc);
    userDoc = userDoc.exists; // <------ exists not exists();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and await userDoc.get(); returned a DocumentSnapshot, but React still said that the exists() method is not defined. My workaround right now is  to use return userDoc != null && (typeof userDoc === "undefined"); but do u know why the exists() method wouldnt work on a doc snapshot?

Comment: @NakulUpadhya, it should be `userDoc.exists` not `userDoc.exists()`

Answer (score 1):

`userDoc = userDoc.get();`

In this line `userDoc.get()` returns a promise and assigns to `userDoc`. When that promise is resolved- you will receive a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) which would then have the `exists` property.

```
userDoc.get()
.then(doc=> {
    if(doc.exists) console.log(doc.data());
})
```

You can look at the [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) in the documentation as to how to read data using javascript sdks.

Comment: I tried this, and even then i'm getting an error that exists() method isnt a function, even though I'm getting a document snapshot object.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo- exists is a [property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#properties) not function, updated code accordingly.